# How do you write Lua code for an input request and then outputs a result from a lookup

Tags: input, lua, output, lookup

I would like some assistance on writing some Lua code in which if a user inputs a color for a car the code will be able to search a lookup table to see if that color is included in the lookup table as a keyword and will be able to output a score which defines the result for example 1 = accept, 2 = decline deepening on what color car they have typed at the beginning.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add any attempts you have made to solve the problem? or any researched possible solutions you have not been able to implement/get working? It is important to include things like this in a question to show you have put some work into the issue.

Comment: i am fairly new to coding but i have been researching and found that the code would need to include io.read to read the user input and search for the keyword and possibly io.write to output the result

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather trivial program in lua. because lua allows for simple creation of associative arrays(a.k.a. hash tables) you can quickly make a lookup table.

```
local carColors = {
    purple = "1"
}
```

From there you index the table with your user input and return your 1 or 2

```
local userInput = io.read():lower() --Make sure to set the user input to all lowercase.
print(carColors[userInput] or "2")  -- if nil return 2
```

I used print rather than io.output.
the or here lets the code handle when the user gives a bad color name when carColors[userInput] is nil the 2 will be printed.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will give this a go